# Unexpected interruption of application

Tags: android, crash

Why, in this very simple example, the last statement (setBackgroundColor) 
produces a crash of the application ?

```
public class Macumba extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       ImageView vista = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.vista);
       vista.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
   }
}
```

main.xml is very simple, too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
   android:id="@+id/widget0"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/vista"
   android:layout_width="300px"
   android:layout_height="330px"
   android:layout_x="9px"
   android:layout_y="8px"
/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Please provide what exception are you getting during crash

Comment: give your stack strace or error that you are getting...

Answer (score 0):

What kind of exception do you get? NullPointerException? If so, it's most likely because vista is null, which is because `R.id.vista` is not in your layout.

Are you sure it's the right main.xml file? And not one from eg. another project?

Comment: The crash produces the following alert message:

Comment: The crash produces the following alert message: Sorry! The application  Macumba (process com.macumba) has stopped unespectedly. Please try again. [Force close]

Comment: You have to provide a stacktrace. When you have Eclipse open, and your phone is connected, open up the `LogCat` view (Window > Show view > Other > LogCat). Then try to run your application, and look in LogCat. Update your question with the content from LogCat.